# Conditional Conformance: Using 'T' as a concrete type conformance to 'T' is not supported

Tags: swift

I have some very basic code as I'm trying to learn about conditional conformance:

```
protocol Animal {
    var name: String { get }
}

protocol Social {
    func speak()
}

class Cat: Animal, Social {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func speak() {
        print("Meow")
    }
}

class Dog: Animal, Social {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func speak() {
        print("Ruff")
    }
}

extension Array: Social where Element: Social {
    func speak() {
        forEach { $0.speak() }
    }
}

let array: [Social] = [Dog(name: "Rocco"), Cat(name: "Gozer")]
array.speak()
```

When trying to execute the last line `array.speak()`, I get the error:

"Using 'Social' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Social' is not supported."

The way I read the line where I extend `Array` is this:
The array conforms to protocol `Social` if all elements in the array conform to `Social`. Is this correct?  The following works just fine:

```
array.forEach { social in
    social.speak()
}
```

Which makes me believe I've done things right, as far as declaring/initializing the array.

I've looked at multiple posts regarding conditional conformance, but none just give me the basics on how to declare the array (if that's my problem) in order to use it and conform to the protocol `Social`.

I'm currently reading the book "Swift Apprentice" by Ray Wenderlich and they show everything except actually using the code in an example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [A protocol does not conform to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/1187415)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the extension to *Element is* rather than *Element conforms to*

```
extension Array where Element == Social {
    func speak() {
        forEach { $0.speak() }
    }
}
```

The constraint `Array : Social` is irrelevant.

Comment: This is a different meaning, however. It means that `[Dog]` will not get `.speak()`.

Comment: @vadian Is this a special use of the `==` operator (was it overloaded for the sake of extensions)?  If I write `let myDog = Dog(name: "Rocco")`  and then `print(myDog == Social)` I get an error that says "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Dog' and 'Social.Protocol'"

Comment: Yes, the `==` operator in a `where` clause is a special case. To check the type write `print(myDog is Social)`

Answer (score 3):

A protocol does not conform to itself. `Element: Social` means that `Element` must be a type that conforms to `Social`. `Social` is not a type that conforms to `Social`. (Imagine if `Social` included an `init()` requirement. What class would `Social()` return? This is why `Social` does not conform to itself.)

In this particular case, you probably want both `[Social]` and `[Dog]` to get `speak()`, and in that case you (somewhat unfortunately) have to say so by duplicating the extension, once for `Element == Social` and once for `Element: Social`.